# Getting a bootstrap element to render on plunker

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm brand new to react and react-bootstrap so I figured I would start out by rendering a bootstrap component on plunker.

This has proven harder than I imagined and I am not sure exactly what I am doing wrong.

Here is the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/mVBVhT1FDliyDpzTR7PJ?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.1/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.27.3/react-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script>
  var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

In the jsx file on the plunk:

```
var ButtonToolbar = ReactBootstrap.ButtonToolbar;
var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
var buttonsInstance = (
  <div>
    <ButtonToolbar>
      <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="large">Large button</Button>
      <Button bsSize="large">Large button</Button>
    </ButtonToolbar>
    <ButtonToolbar>
      <Button bsStyle="primary">Default button</Button>
      <Button>Default button</Button>
    </ButtonToolbar>
    <ButtonToolbar>
      <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="small">Small button</Button>
      <Button bsSize="small">Small button</Button>
    </ButtonToolbar>
    <ButtonToolbar>
      <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="xsmall">Extra small button</Button>
      <Button bsSize="xsmall">Extra small button</Button>
    </ButtonToolbar>
  </div>
);

React.render(buttonsInstance, document.getElementById('example');
```

I just pasted in the examples and then made some changes based on some github threads to try to get it working but I am not having any joy.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your toolbar doesn't start until after the closing HTML tag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I cut and paste the sample on website.  Can you explain what you mean as I don't get it.  Thanks :)

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  This is just a paste of code from the plunk.  Please follow the link and you can see the code is in a separate file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closed parenthesis. Change this:

```
React.render(buttonsInstance, document.getElementById('example');
```

into this:

```
React.render(buttonsInstance, document.getElementById('example'));
```

Also, if you want the buttons to be rendered you should remove the call to `React.render` coming from the plunk example code:

```
/*
React.render(
  <h1>Rendered from script.jsx!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
*/
```